# rollback transaction associate with more than one session in Spring MVC + Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, session, spring-mvc, rollback

I am using Spring **MVC + Hibernate** , the following is **generic method** for save ( one - to Many). **I use this to insert the record for both table with the same session, if any one table fail, then all operation roll beck because they are associate with same session**

```
public <T, E> long save(T entity, List<E> list) throws DataAccessException {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    long getGenVal=(Long)session.save(entity);
    for(E getlist : list){
    session.save(getlist);
    }

    return getGenVal;
}
```

**In Controller**

```
@Resource(name = "PersistenceTemplate")
private PersistenceTemplate pt;
long getGenVal=pt.save(purchaseReq,list);
```

Now I want to maintain **audit log**, for this purpose I add another argument in same method (save)to associate this operation with same session, so that if any table of 3 tables, create problem. Then transaction rollback automatically. ( spring feature)

```
public <T, E, K> long save(T entity, List<E> list, K audit) throws DataAccessException {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        long getGenVal=(Long)session.save(entity);
        for(E getlist : list){
        session.save(getlist);
        }
        session.save(audit);
        return getGenVal;
    }
```

**so All three operation associate with same session**

But Not I have a problem , **because Audit Trail (log) entity required Id of newly insert Record** such as ( In Controller )

```
purchaseReqAT= new ProPurchReqATModel("NEW REQUISION", "INSERT", 1, userId, userIp, sysdate);
```

**["INSERT", 1, userId]**  1 between INSERT and userId is **ID**  **(PK)** that is newly generated !

If I create a separate method to save the audit trail after getting the id of new inserted record. such as

```
public <T> long save(T auditTrail) throws DataAccessException {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    long getGenVal=(Long) session.save(auditTrail);
    return getGenVal;
}
```

and audit trail fails to insert the record in table, how can I roll back all previous transaction ? and how we can associate the new generated ID with audit trial within same method .

any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a service layer which incorporates this, and the service layer should be the transactional layer. The service should call the different repositories/daos, this way everything happens in a single transaction.

It also simplifies your controller code (that should merely be a thin layer between your web request and the calling of a service method it should not contain business logic).

However for writing an audit record I would write a [hibernate interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch14.html), that way writing your audit records is transparent and you don't forget to include it in the data modification records.